# Wget server issues or the command is wrong?

Tags: server, downloads, remote, wget

I have a file on my server that is changing constantly, it changes hourly, sometimes it changes every minute. The file is is growing, but not so fast.

This file is generated inside a dir called `/home/my_user/backup123/subnets.cfg`, until here no problem.

**This is my first question:**
Now I need to put this file on a remote server. What is the best way to do this?
From my local server, that where the file is located or across the remote server?

**Here is my second question:**
If I do across the remote server I think I need to use the **wget** command right?
I have tried to use this command:

```
 wget --user=my-user --password=password http://example.com/dir/subnets.cfg
```

But it is not working, it tells me "wrong user name". Of course I had use my own user name and password, but it is not working. I have permissions to the file and dir.

I need to get the subnets.cfg file and put it on my remote server, how can I do that?

Comment: perheps I can use the wget inside the cron jobs, something like this ->  0 0 * * 0 wget --mirror http://example.com/dir/subnets.cfg -o /home/my_user/my_files/  But it is only the idea, firstly I need everything above working properly.. :)

Comment: make sure that user is the .htaccess user and password the .htaccess password.

Comment: I do not have a .htaccess file in my server, nor local neither remote.

Comment: @Fernando Maybe it's hidden, if you really don't have a .htaccess file, remove the --user and --password args.

Comment: but it is 2 linux server, all file is being showed to me.. I had tried without user and password .. I get the nothing.. I'm trying to connect as root and nothing.. I know is not the best way try to connect as root, but I'm testing.. if works I'll create a new user only to the task.

Comment: @Fernando If you are running nautilus press `Ctrl+H` to show hidden files. If you are running in console mode, try `ls -a`.

Comment: I'm running a shell command line, and I do not have the .htaccess file. And it do not accept the blank user and password.. :/

Comment: There are some other command similar to wget? something specific for ftp or ssh? or wget do all of them?

Comment: @Fernando Are you trying to download a file on the ftp server with wget over the http protocol?

Comment: @Fernando If yes, look at my answer.

Comment: @Fernando I edited your question a bit. The only line I don't understand is: `From my local server, that where the file is located or across the remote server?`. What do you mean?

Comment: @Daniel I mean. I have 2 systems in 2 different servers, and I need the systems talk with each other. The server 1 (local), generates a file, then the server 2 (remote) reads a file and reloads yourself every time it reads a file from server 1 (local). Here I call like this Local and Remote, but I can call whatever name.. server 1 and server 2 .. just this! The wget command I want to do is, to get the file from server 1 and put it in the server 2.. I will try the command of your answer, and I tell you after, how was it.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download a file from a FTP server over wget, you have to type:

```
wget -t 10 -nH -P backup -r ftp://USER:PASSWORD@ftp.example.com/dir/subnets.cfg
```

Replace `USER` with your ftp username and `PASSWORD` with your ftp password.

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thanks, that's it man! Your help was completly useful to me.